# What is the correct way to use RefCount

Tags: c#, rx.net

```
var x = Observable.Return(1)
    .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine("creating"))
    .Replay()
    .RefCount();
x.Subscribe(); //first subscription
x.Subscribe(); //second subscription
```

Result:

```
creating
creating
```

The "creating" is supported to be print only once here.

But the first subscription seems get disposed before the second subscription starting
, the reference count go back to zero and the Replay disconnected.

So what's the correct way to use the RefCount in a situation that we don't know how soon our source will get completed and we want to subscribe it multiple times?

Comment: What happens when you remove `.Replay().`?

Comment: Also "creating" twice

Comment: Looks to me you favor Connect() instead of RefCount().  http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#RefCount

Comment: Yes, ur right.But actually in my real situation, the replay stream will be passed to the next recursive, so i have no idea when to disconnect it. it would be nice to if i can use refcount there